# How to check if object does NOT contain an item in NUnit?

Tags: c#, nunit

Is there a way to check if an object does NOT contain an item in NUnit? The `NUnit.Framework.Assert.Contains()` method checks if an item is contained, but I am looking for the opposite here. A lot of methods have a negative counterpart (like `Assert.NotNull()`, `Assert.AreNotEqual()` and `Assert.DoesNotThrow()`), but `Contains()` Seems to be lacking such an opposite method.

The only way I found is checking it manually using `Assert.That()`, but that is a little bit clunky and doesn't read as well.

```
Assert.That(!result.Dependencies.Contains<string>("tableName"));
```

Comment: your method would just be syntactic sugar. if you _insist_ on not having the `!` around, why don't you just write an extension method `DoesNotContain()`? (although personally, i'd prefer the exclamation mark)

Comment: True, but I was wondering why most methods have an opposite method and `Contains()` does not seem to have one, unless I missed anything. I will probably (have to) stick with the `!` though indeed.

Comment: because nobody cared to implement it? also: `why most methods have an opposite method` - citation needed. i would definitely _not_ agree to this statement in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe these should work:

```
Assert.That(result.Dependencies, Does.Not.Contain("tableName"));

Assert.That(result.Dependencies, Has.None.EqualTo("tableName"));
```

In general, the framework has not added new "Classic" assertions for some years. DoesNotContain would be easy to implement, so you can always ask the project for it if you prefer the older syntax.

@Commenters... The problem with `Assert.That(bool condition)` is that it doesn't give a very good error message, so I can understand why @Axel doesn't want to use it. Of course, it can be used with an error message specified, but that's more typing. :-)